# How to solve this weibull distribution equation using least square?

Tags: probability-distributions, least-squares

$$f_y=e^{-[(A_y+\delta)/\gamma]^\delta}$$

I'm not sure how to I derive the least square method to solve the unknown parameter for delta and gamma. Any help would be appreciated.

What I did tried to do is to get along the line of bringing down the power of e using the ln function, and applied another ln function to the following equation after the first ln to bring down the delta. That's where I'm stuck at.

Comment: Can you clarify the situation? Do you have an empirical density curve (histogram) and you want to least-square-fit the TWO parameters $\delta$ and $\gamma$, where $A_y$ is known and somehow it is justified to assume the noise are independentt Gaussian?